# Access BitBucket Repository via Pipeline of Another Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have 2 repositories: `A` and `B`. Repository `B` is required by `A` during build time. `B` is included as a submodule in `A`. Thus, in `A` I have `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "src/assets/B"]
    path = src/assets/B
    url = https://bitbucket.org/org_name/B.git
```

The `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` of `A` has the following command to initialize the submodule:

```
git submodule update --init
```

For `A` I have enabled the Pipelines and generated an SSH key pair (public and private).

For `B` I have copied the aforementioned public key to the Access Key section so that the Pipelines of `A` can `git clone` `B`.

I am getting an authentication error.

`fatal: could not read Password for 'https://my_username@bitbucket.org'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, use the SSH URL instead of the HTTPS URL. Let me know if it works I'll post it as an answer.